# Using a large csv: how to remove redundant dropdown options in a dash callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using a large csv file with state, county, and then a bunch of data specific to each county. In Dash, I am trying to use a series of callbacks to allow a user to select by state, then by county, and then they add or remove county-specific data as they desire. My df:

```
df = [dict(State="CO", County="Franklin", Task="Job A", Start='2020-01-01', Finish='2020-02-28'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Franklin", Task="Job A", Start='2020-03-01', Finish='2020-04-28'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Franklin", Task="Job B", Start='2020-05-05', Finish='2020-06-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Franklin", Task="Job B", Start='2020-06-05', Finish='2020-07-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Franklin", Task="Job B", Start='2020-08-05', Finish='2020-09-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Franklin", Task="Job B", Start='2020-10-05', Finish='2020-12-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Wise", Task="Job A", Start='2020-01-01', Finish='2020-02-28'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Wise", Task="Job A", Start='2020-03-01', Finish='2020-04-28'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Wise", Task="Job B", Start='2020-05-05', Finish='2020-06-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Wise", Task="Job B", Start='2020-06-05', Finish='2020-07-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Wise", Task="Job B", Start='2020-08-05', Finish='2020-09-15'),
      dict(State="CO", County="Wise", Task="Job B", Start='2020-10-05', Finish='2020-12-15'),
```

Using a dropdown callback, I populate the dropdown options with:

```
dcc.Dropdown(id='location-choice',
             options=[{'label': x['County'], 'value': x['County']} for x in df],
             other attributes, etc)
```

but it loads every “CO” for every row in the csv file in my state dropdown (this example would provide 12 identical COs in the dropdown) and every county row in the csv file for my county dropdown (this example would provide 6 Franklins and 6 Wises in the dropdown).

They all work if selected and load all the rows pertinent to the selection on my graph (example: selecting CO and Franklin still loads both Job A’s and all 4 Job B’s) which is what I want.

**In summary: How do I remove the redundant options from the dropdown while still preserving those rows in the df for graphing purposes?**

Thank you!

Edit: Thank you to coralvanda. Their solution solved the redundant dropdown options in both location and task selection, but I'm having a hard time following the changes I need to update my timeline graph. The following is my function to update my graph which works well without pandas (takes county and task selection, just with redundant selection options), so I think I am just trying to cure my ignorance of pandas at this point.

```
    def build_graph(location_selected, job_selected):

        print(job_selected)
        print(location_selected)

        dff = [d for d in df if d['County'] in location_selected] 
        dff = [d for d in dff if d['Task'] in job_selected]


        fig = px.timeline(
            data_frame=dff,
            x_start='Start',
            x_end='Finish',
            y='Task',
```

I get the following error:

```
line 130, in <listcomp>
     dff = [d for d in df if d['County'] in location_selected]
     TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Since my csv file has these columns: [State,County,Task,Tool,Start,End], I changed to:

```
        dff = [d for d in df if d[1] in location_selected] 
        dff = [d for d in dff if d[2] in job_selected]
```

Running at this point gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Value of 'y' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of [] but received: Task
```

From here I have tried a few options, but using using print(dff.shape) before and after:

```
        print(job_selected)
        print(location_selected)
        dff=df
        print(df.shape)
        print(dff.shape)
        dff = [d for d in df if d[1] in location_selected]
        print(dff.shape)
        dff = [d for d in dff if d[2] in job_selected]
        print(dff.shape)
```

shows that dff is behaving weird:

```
['Job A', 'Job B']
['Franklin']
(4101, 6)
[]
[]
```

if I choose another county:

```
['Job A', 'Job B']
Bath
(4101, 6)
['State', 'Start']
[]
```

And if I change the job_selected, that responds with an appropriately changed list.

Any help on figuring out this final part would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.unique()` method in `pandas`. The example you gave is using counties, so I'll stick with that, but this same thing should work for the other dropdowns. I'm guessing this is the column name.

```py
dcc.Dropdown(id='location-choice',
             options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['County'].unique(),
             other attributes, etc)
```

If that doesn't quite do it, you may need to cast it as a list using the pandas `tolist()` method like this:

`df['County'].unique().tolist()`

I haven't run this locally, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll take another look.

Edit: I realized that you don't have the CSV as a `pandas.DataFrame` in your example. If you haven't done that already, you can easily do `df = pandas.read_csv()` and pass in the file location. Then you can use the pandas methods on the data frame.

Edit 2:
Getting used to pandas can take a little time, though I believe the payoff will be well worth the effort. If I'm understanding your new problem correctly, it sounds like you need to select a subset of your data frame based on the user's dropdown selections. You can do that like this:

```py
dff = df[df['County'].isin(location_selected) & df['Task'].isin(job_selected)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I used df = pd.read_csv() as you suggested, and .unique() solved the dropdown problem, but I have run into issues with my callback now.  To provide more context, I am updating my original post.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your new problem.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but there is a quirk. As is, the automatically provided county location value (multi=False) works and job selection dropdown (multi=True) works well. Once I change the county location, the app throws a TypeError because the County Select dropdown is returning a string instead of a list. Oddly, just making everything exactly the same, I switched the county location to multi=True and everything works as intended (wonderful feeling) but this breaks when I add more than one county. Thoughts on multi=False returning a string but multi=True returns a list? Thank you!!!

Comment: Yes, `multi=True` should return a list, and the `.isin()` method requires an iterable. If `multi=False`, then the `value` prop will probably be a string. You could add a check to the callback, such as `if isinstance(location_selected, str)` and have that do `df['County'].eq(location_selected)]`, then keep the `.isin()` for lists.